# How to tell React Component that the HTML Page calling it is active

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to reuse my HTML Navigation Bar using React and Angular Directives and I'm a little confused on how to approach it

This is my navigationbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="source.html">Source</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is my AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("NavBar", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl : 'navigationbar.html'
    };
});
```

In all of my HTML Files I can call this navigation bar fine, but the problem is I don't know how to place the `<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>` and "active" class on the right html page according to which html page is calling the navigation bar. How can I move the tags to contact.html when the user is on the contact page?

I was thinking of using React, something like this:

```
render() {
if (this.state.active ???) {
  return <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to set it up the condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a React application, if you have a piece of data that will affect your entire application, you generally put that data in a "state variable", in the highest component in your application, ie. the one you render with `ReactDOM.render`.  Typically (eg. in `create-react-app`) this component is called `App`.

Then using either context or props, you need to pass that state variable down to any components that use it (eg. your menu).  This way, whenever you need to "change pages", you just change that state, and then your components will update themselves based on it automatically.